# DataGridView scrolling behaviour

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, datagridview, scrollbars

I have a DataGridView which has vertical and horizontal scrollbars.
When I scroll it vertically it is not possible to make any of rows to be partially visible. In other words: `scrollbarPosition % rowHeigth == 0` at all times.
But when i scroll horizontally DataGridView does not behave this way. Column can be partially visible. How can I make it impossible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

DataGridView was not designed that way.
It's completely impossible, unless you rewrite substantial portions of the control.

Most grid controls, including Excel, Access, and Outlook, as well as most if not all 3rd-party .Net grids, have the same limitation.

Comment: +! Yup, doesnt look like its supported (http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winforms/thread/57ab22a5-b8af-4d16-a654-80f8ce59c872/). You'll have to create something custom like SLaks says.